# how do I convert json data into Html tag?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display JSON data in the Html tag. But I got the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError.

```js
async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    
        document.getElementById("display").insertAdjacentText = `
        ${data.articles.map(function (article) {
            return `
            <ul id="news-articles">
            <li class="article"><img class="article-img" src="${article.urlToImage}" alt="article-img"></li>
            <li class="article"><h2 class="article-title">${article.title}</h2></li>
            <li class="article"><p class="article-description">${article.description}</p></li>
           <li class="article"><span class="article-author">${article.author}</span></li>
            <li class="article"><a class="article-link" href="">${article.url} target="_blank"> </a></li>
            </ul>
             `
        }).join('')}`
    
    }
    fetchData();
```

```html
<div class="display"></div>
```

Comment: Note that if there is more than one article, you will have more than one `ul` with the id `news-articles`, which is invalid HTML. Any script which refers to that id will only get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are inserting HTML entities as text, which is not going to work.

Try

```js
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

        document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].innerHTML = data.articles.map(function (article) {
            return `
            <ul id="news-articles">
            <li class="article"><img class="article-img" src="${article.urlToImage}" alt="article-img"></li>
            <li class="article"><h2 class="article-title">${article.title}</h2></li>
            <li class="article"><p class="article-description">${article.description}</p></li>
           <li class="article"><span class="article-author">${article.author}</span></li>
            <li class="article"><a class="article-link" href="">${article.url} target="_blank"> </a></li>
            </ul>`;
        }).join('');

    }
    fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your div element is of class `display`, not id `display`, and thus `document.getElementById("display")` returns null. Change `class="display"` to `id="display"`.

Also, use `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You referenced by `id="display"`, but it was set to `class="display"`.

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76');
  const data = await response.json();

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = data["articles"].map(
    article => `<ul id="news-articles">
            <li class="article"><img class="article-img" src="${article.urlToImage}" alt="article-img"></li>
            <li class="article"><h2 class="article-title">${article.title}</h2></li>
            <li class="article"><p class="article-description">${article.description}</p></li>
           <li class="article"><span class="article-author">${article.author}</span></li>
            <li class="article"><a class="article-link" href="">${article.url} target="_blank"> </a></li></ul>`).join('');
}

fetchData();
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```